# 12.04 LTS Side-scrolling for touch pad?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, scrolling

I know that you can set the touch pad to scroll on the right side, but is it possible to scroll left and right? I mean, when there are websites that require side scrolling, is it possible to swipe on the top or bottom of the touch pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Open Systems settings then click "Mouse and Touchpad"

Open the touchpad tab and then enable both "two finger scrolling" and "horizontal scrolling"

I actually disabled this feature after trying it for a while because I found it annoying if the screen scrolled horizontally when all I wanted was a vertical scroll.